# Calculate all of the second order partial derivatives of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

My attempt:

$g_x$ = 3$x^2$-6x

$g_y$ = 3$y^2$-12y

$g_{xx}$ = 6x-6

$g_{yy}$ = 6y-12

$g_{xy}$ = 0

$g_{yx}$ = 0

Are these correct? Also would I be correct in saying that $g_{xy}$ = $g_{yx}$ for all functions?

Comment: All those are correct. You wouldn't be correct in saying that though. What you're looking for is Schwarz' theorem which states that it is true, provided the second partial derivatives are continuous. You can find more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right for all the partial derivatives. The result that the "mixed" partial derivatives are equal for all functions is true (given some very basic conditions) and is called [Clairaut's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem).